# Spec is missing in Allure report if an error occurred in setup methods

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spock, geb, allure, autotest

In my GEB + Selenium Webdriver tests there are some UI actions in `setupSpec()` methods (common case, I believe). The problem is that if there is an exception in those steps, the whole spec is completely missing in the final report, but it's logical to **see the tests of that spec marked as ignored in the report**.

This is a real problem, because the build can pass with the success percentage of 100%, despite there are tests which didn't start.

A `\build\allure-results\<id>-result.json` file is not generated for that spec. 
Here is the example to reproduce the issue:

Spec #1 (With an exception, expected to be shown as ignored):

```groovy
@Stepwise
@Feature("Job")
@Story("Spec with exception in setup")
class SetupExceptionTest extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setupSpec() {
        println 'in setup spec'
        throw new ElementNotInteractableException('some error')
    }

    def 'Test 1'() {
        setup:
        println 'in test 1'
        expect:
        2 == 2
    }

    def 'Test 2'() {
        setup:
        println 'in test 2'
        expect:
        2 == 3
    }

    def cleanupSpec() {}
}
```

Spec #2 (With no exception in setup):

```groovy
@Stepwise
@Feature("Job")
@Story("Spec with no exception in setup")
class SetupTest extends GebReportingSpec {

    def setupSpec() {
        println 'in setup spec'
    }

    def 'Test 1'() {
        setup:
        println 'in test 1'
        expect:
        2 == 2
    }

    def 'Test 2'() {
        setup:
        println 'in test 2'
        expect:
        2 == 3
    }

    def cleanupSpec() {}
}
```

The launch command: `gradlew clean test -PignoreTestFailures=true allureServe` produces the following report:

[image]

So there is no `SetupExceptionTest` spec in any of report sections. 
Are there any settings to change this behavior? Or maybe known workarounds?

The following versions used:

```
testCompile group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '1.2-groovy-2.4'
testCompile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-spock', version: '2.7.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used Allure reports before, gave it a quick spin with the latest version allure-spock 2.12.1 and Spock 1.3-groovy-2.5 in my Maven project. Maven test run fails because there seems to be a dependency missing, but when I run the two tests from my IDE, the test get executed at least.

As you said, I also see *[UUID]-result.json* files being generated for `SetupTest` but not for `SetupExceptionTest`. So if Allure does not create these files in case of a test setup error, no fancy HTML report can be generated either. This looks like an Allure problem to me, either in Allure core or in the Spock integration.

What happens for JUnit tests? Do they behave the same or differently?

In any case, if I comment out the Allure annotations in your tests and run them with Maven Surefire, there is a report generated for `SetupExceptionTest`, which means that neither Spock nor Maven are the problem. I think you ought to look at Allure because by elimination this is the only remaining component in the tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a workaround I used.

In the base class:

```
@Shared
protected Throwable setupSpecThrowable

def setup() {
    if (setupSpecThrowable) {
        throw setupSpecThrowable
    }
}

def cleanupSpec() {
    setupSpecThrowable = null
}

protected def withSetupErrorCatch(Closure closure) {
    try {
        closure()
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        setupSpecThrowable = t
    }
}
```

In each test class:

```
def setupSpec() {
    def data = getSetupSpecData()
   
    withSetupErrorCatch {

        //actions that can throw something
        
    }
}
```

This catches any exception in `setupSpec()` and throws it in `setup()` so that allure can see and record the test.